# Возведение в степень.Длинная арифметика

Tags: c, массивы, biginteger

Пытаюсь возвести в степень , алгоритм такой  : ввожу число,( сохраняю в массиве в обратном порядке , где нулевой элемент - это количество цифр числа , а остальное сами цифры числа , записанные в обратном порядке с начала массива) ввожу степень , и копирую оригинальный массив в *сv* и *сv2* и и вызываю функцию n-1 раз , в которой передаю указатели на массивы , потом умножаю их в функции и записываю результат в массив *y* ,в главной программе копирую в *cv* *y* ,чтобы при новом вызове функции то же самое введенное число пользователем(которое было сохранено в а  и сохранено в cv ) умножилось на результат первого умножения (то есть cv на cv2)
И вроде бы ответ почти  правильный ,но при вводе 15 в 3 степени получается 57600 , а не 50625

```
void stepen(int* cv, int* cv2,int* y) {
int u = 0, k = 0, j = 0, i = 0,cr=0,v=0,t=0;

    cr = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= cv[0]; i++) {

        for (j = 1; j <= cv2[0]; j++) {
            cr = cv[i] * cv2[j];
            k = i + j - 1;
            while (cr > 0) {
                cr = cr + y[k];
                y[k] = cr % 10;
                cr = cr / 10;
                if (k > y[0]) y[0] = k;
                k = k + 1;
            }

        }

        }
    }

case'^': {
    int n = 0;
    int cv[N+5];
    int cv2[N+5];

    printf("Enter the first number ");
    readlong(a);
    printf("\nEnter the stepen ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < N+5; i++) {
        cv[i] = a[i];
        cv2[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (t = 0; t < n-1; t++) {
        stepen(cv, cv2, y);
        for (zxc = 0; zxc < N + 5; zxc++) {
            cv2[zxc] = 0;
            cv2[zxc] = y[zxc];
        }
    }
        writelong(y);

    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам желательно овладеть некоторыми приемами отладки кода. (И, конечно, не называть функцию, вычисляющую произведение,  `stepen`.)

Вы возводите 15 в куб, считая, что функция `stepen` работает правильно. Вы в этом убедились? Вы же знаете, что после первого умножения 15 на 15 должно получиться 225. Получается? Напишите функцию, которая выводит Ваше длинное число из массива целых, и вызывайте ее два раза в начале функции `stepen` с `cv` и `cv2`, и один раз в конце с `y`. Таким образом, Вы будете совершенно точно знать, что Вы перемножаете, и какой получается результат. А также сможете убедиться в том, что повторные вызовы работают с результатом предыдущего умножения.

И в заключение, 15 в 3-й степени это 3375, а не 50625.

Comment: да и в добавок допишу:  убрать лишние переменные и инициализировать их лучше по месту... код станет проще и понятнее быстрее сами разберетесь, и хранить длинные числа можно в строках.. и работая с ними как со строками и разбирая их как массивы.. это удобно

Comment: Нашёл,исправил вашим способом , всё работает, теперь правильно возводит в  любую степень,спасиб

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошо что автор сам разобрался, как раз и не хотелось мешать.
Подобные алгоритмы встречаются так же при преобразовании систем счисления.
Решая вашу задачу, получился вот такой вариант, на оптимальность не претендую, а так же возможны недочёты)), *проверяйте не отходя от кассы(с):*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5 // степень 
#define M 5 // размер числа

void multiply(int* in1, int* in2) {
    int cr;
    int tmp[N + 5];
    for (int i = 0; i <= in2[0]; i++)
        tmp[i] = in2[i];

    in2[0] = 0; // будем считать что переменная чистая    
    for (int i = 1; i <= in1[0]; i++) 
        for (int j = 1; j <= tmp[0]; j++) {
            cr = in1[i] * tmp[j];
            for(int k = i + j - 1; cr > 0; k++) {
                if (k > in2[0])
                    in2[0] = k;
                else
                    cr += in2[k];
                in2[k] = cr % 10;
                cr /= 10;
            }
     }
}
void writelong(int* y){
    for (int i = y[0]; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d",y[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int y[N*M];
    int out[N*M];

/*  int a[N]; */
    int a[] = {2,5,1}; /* First number 15 */
    n = M;             /* Degree of number  5*/

    for (int i = 1; i < N * M; i++)
        out[i] = 0;

/*  printf("Enter the first number ");
    readlong(a); 
    printf("\nEnter the stepen "); 
    scanf _s("%d", &n);*/
    y[0] = y[1] = 1;    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        multiply(a,y);
    writelong(a);
    printf("^%d=",M);
    writelong(y);
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/7BY4cb)
Или онлайн дебаггер-компилятор, если не установлен у кого, а попробовать есть желание, можно дальше оптимизировать...
https://onlinegdb.com/S1cN_2Szf